# Python 2.7 Selenium No Such Element on Website

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do some webscraping from a betting website:

As part of the process, I have to click on the different buttons under the "Favourites" section on the left side to select different competitions.

Let's take the ENG Premier League button as example. I identified the button as:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [666kb.com](http://666kb.com/i/e07b9ydvklckwh6c5.png))</sub>

The XPath is: `//*[@id="SportMenuF"]/div[3]` and the ID is 91.

My code for clicking on the button is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_path = "C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("URL Removed")

content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SportMenuF"]/div[3]')
content.click()
```

Unfortunately, I always get this error message when I run the script:

```
"no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="SportMenuF"]/div[3]"}"
```

I have tried different identifiers such as CCS Selector, ID and, as shown in the example above, the Xpath. I tried using waits and explicit conditions, too. None of this has worked.

I also attempted scraping some values from the website without any success:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = "C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("URL removed")


content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('price-val')

for entry in content:
    print entry.text
```

Same problem, nothing shows up.

The website embeddes an iframe from a different website. Could this be the cause of my problems? I tried scraping directly from the iframe URL, too, which didn't work, either.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes elements are either hiding behind an iframe, or they haven't loaded yet

For the iframe check, try:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
```

For the wait check, try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '-put the x-path here-')))
```